# Java 8 lambda style wrapper for JDBC statement execution

Tags: java, jdbc, lambda, functional-programming

I have some wrapper class for JDBC statement execution with many methods like following:

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) {
    try (Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement()) {
        return statement.executeQuery(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("My custom statement execution failure", e);
    }
}

public int executeUpdate(String sql) {
    try (Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement()) {
        return statement.executeUpdate(sql);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("My custom statement execution failure", e);
    }
}

...
```

So there are a lot of methods that are different only with 1) return type and 2) actual delegated method.

I would like to pass executable call in Ruby's lambda fashion, to reduce boilerplate code to something like this:

```
public Boolean executeQuery(String sql) {
    return wrapException(s -> {s.executeQuery(sql)});
}

private <T> wrapException(Function<Statement, <T>> query)throws Exception {
    try  (Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement()) {
        return query.apply(statement);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Two things I currently fail to wrap my head around are:

1. how to preserve generic return type of the wrappedQuery function
2. s.executeQuerty(sql) still complains about unhandled SQLException,
   so effectively I'm not able to wrap all exception handling away

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you forgot to rename `wrapException` to `wrappedQuery`?

Comment: @nullpointer oh yeah, thanks, copy/paste issue :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `Function<Statement, <T>>` is not valid syntax. It should be just `Function<Statement, T>`. Apparently, you are confusing the declaration of a type parameter, like at the method’s beginning (`<T>`) with the use of the type parameter, which should be a plain name, like `T`. Note that, likely for the same reason, your method lacks a return type. There should be a `<T>` to declare the type parameter, followed by a `T` to declare the return type before the method’s name.
2. Your method `wrapException` still declares `throws Exception` which is even worse than the JDBC methods which only declare to throw `SQLException`. This contradicts the whole intention.
3. A value returning lambda expression should either, follow the expression syntax,
   like `s -> s.executeQuery(sql)`, or contain a `return` statement, e.g. `s -> { return s.executeQuery(sql); }`. Your expression `s -> {s.executeQuery(sql)}` is an incomplete (missing semicolon) statement syntax without a `return`. Also, you are declaring a `Boolean` return type despite that `executeQuery` returns a `ResultSet`.
4. The functional interface [`java.util.function.Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/function/Function.html) declares the function method [`apply`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-) which does not declare any checked exceptions, therefore you can’t implement it via a lambda expression which could throw checked exceptions like `SQLException`. So for your use case, you need a different functional interface.

   You may make the exception type generic to allow your custom functional interface to be reused at other places where you need a `Function` that may throw a particular exception. E.g.

   ```
   public interface ThrowingFunction<T,R,E extends Exception> {
       R apply(T input) throws E;
   }
   ```

with this, you may declare

```
public ResultSet executeQuery(String sql) {
    return wrapException(s -> s.executeQuery(sql));
}
public int executeUpdate(String sql) {
    return wrapException(s -> s.executeUpdate(sql));
}
private <T> T wrapException(ThrowingFunction<Statement, T, SQLException> operation) {
    try(Statement statement = this.connection.createStatement()) {
        return operation.apply(statement);
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

---

But note that there is a general problem independent from the Generics/lambda usage that applies to your original code as well:

[`Statement.close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#close--)

> **Note:** When a `Statement` object is closed, its current `ResultSet` object, if one exists, is also closed.

The whole purpose of the `try(…)` statement is to ensure that the resource will be closed immediately when leaving the block, so returning a `ResultSet` from there is pointless. (This does not apply to the `executeUpdate` though). One way to fix this, would be to pass a function to process the `ResultSet` right within the block.

```
public <R> R executeQuery(String sql, ThrowingFunction<ResultSet,R,SQLException> op) {
    return wrapException(s -> op.apply(s.executeQuery(sql)));
}
```

This allows the function to return an arbitrary value not depending on the `ResultSet` anymore, e.g.

```
String value = executeQuery("SELECT STRING_COL FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID=42",
                            rs -> rs.next()? rs.getString(1): null);
int max = executeQuery("SELECT MAX(INTVAL_COL) FROM SOME_TABLE",
                       rs -> rs.next()? rs.getInt(1): -1);
```